# How to use pika in a blocking manner?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, race-condition, pika

I am trying to use pika to do the most basic rabbitmq connection, queue declaration, sending a single message and receiving a single message.

It looks like pika is non-blocking, and calling back to back API calls to a dockerized rabbit causes a race-condition.

For example:

```
channel.queue_declare(queue_name)
time.sleep(5)
channel.queue_bind(queue=queue_name, exchange=queue_params.exchange,
                                   routing_key=queue_params.routing_key)
```

succeeds.

However,

```
channel.queue_declare(queue_name)
channel.queue_bind(queue=queue_name, exchange=queue_params.exchange,
                                   routing_key=queue_params.routing_key)
```

fails on `queue_bind` with

```
pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker: (404, "NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'fleet' in vhost '/'")
```

---

Trying to busy-wait:

```
    def on_declare_ok():
        while True:  # TODO busy waiting until a better way is found
            try:
                print(f"Attempting to bind {queue_name}")
                channel.queue_bind(queue=queue_name, exchange=queue_params.exchange,
                                   routing_key=queue_params.routing_key)
                print(f"Successful bind to {queue_name}")
                break
            except pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker as ex:
                time.sleep(0.1)
            except pika.exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError as ex:
                time.sleep(0.1)

        print(f"Attempting to declare {queue_name}")
        channel.queue_declare(queue_name)
        print(f"Successfully declared {queue_name}")

    on_declare_ok()
```

also does no good, this enters an infinite loop of

```
Attempting to bind queue_name
```

---

I expected pika to handle all of this internally, and I assume I am doing something incorrectly.

I am also encountering these race conditions on other pika API calls, even though everything is single-threaded (except for the rabbit server which runs in another docker container).

What's the best way of using pika in a blocking way?

Answer (score 0):

The error says your **exchange** does not exist at the point you're trying to bind your queue:

```
"NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'fleet' in vhost '/'"
```

Comment: correct, it doesn't exist. As you can see in the linked question, I assert existence just before the call, which by itself causes it to get closed. No idea what it is. Thanks for the mailing list suggestion

Comment: You are confusing a queue with an exchange. There is nothing in your code to create the requested exchange named "fleet".